# Store information/reference about structure

Tags: go, struct, reflection, slice, go-xorm

I am looking for a way to store information which struct a function should use. Each struct corresponds to certain database table.

```
type Record struct {
   TableName string
   PrimaryKey string
   //XormStruct // how can I store User or Post here?
   XormStruct2 interface{} // see I have tried below
   XormStruct3 reflect.Type // see I have tried below
}

var posts []Post

var ListOfTables [...]Record {
   {"User", "id", User},
   //{"Post", "post_id", Post},
   {"Post", "post_id", posts, reflect.TypeOf([]Post{})},
}

// User is xorm struct
type User struct {
   Id int64
   Name string
}

// Post is xorm struct
type Post struct {
   Post_id int64
   Name string
   Other string
}
```

I want to be able to dynamically choose struct for table.

```
for _, rec := range ListOfTables {
    //var entries []rec.XormStruct // this does not work, of course
    //var entries []reflect.TypeOf(rec.XormStruct) // this does not work either
    // xorm is *xorm.Engine
    xorm.Find(&entries)
    //xorm.Find(&rec.XormStruct2) //with interface{}, does not work - produces an empty &[]
    posts3 := reflect.New(rec.XormStruct3).Interface()
    //xorm.Find(&posts3) // same as above, produces empty &[]
    var posts []Post
    xorm.Find(&posts) // produces desired data

    // afterwards I will do same to any table entries, e.g.
    xml.Marshal(entries)
    // so there is really no need to create identical functions for each table
}
```

Goal DRY (I have about 30 tables, function is the same)

I have tried:

- to use `reflect.TypeOf()`, but I do not understand if/how I can use it (`reflect.Type`) to define a new variable
- Define Record with `XormStruct interface{}` and for each ListOfTables entry create a slice e.g. `var posts []Post` and `{"Post", "post_id", posts},`
- Searching SO and godocs

It seems to me, that `xorm.Find()` is not "happy" about getting an `interface{}` instead of `[]Posts` even if it does not say so.

**UPDATE:**
I believe the breaking difference is this:

```
spew.Dump(posts3) //posts3 := reflect.New(rec.XormStruct3).Interface()
// (*[]main.Post)<0x2312312>(<nil>)
spew.Dump(posts) //var posts []Post
// ([]main.Post)<nil>
```

**SOLUTION**

```
posts3 := reflect.New(rec.XormStruct3).Interface()
xorm.Find(posts3) // not &posts3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) to represent / describe a Go type. And at runtime, you may use [`reflect.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New) to obtain a pointer to the zeroed value of this type wrapped in a [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value). And if you need a slice instead of a single value, you may use [`reflect.SliceOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceOf), or obtain the type descriptor of the slice value in the first place.

If you store `refect.Type` values of your tables, this is how you can use it:

```
type Record struct {
   TableName  string
   PrimaryKey string
   XormStruct reflect.Type
}

var ListOfTables [...]Record {
   {"User", "id", reflect.TypeOf((*User)(nil)).Elem()},
   {"Post", "post_id", reflect.TypeOf((*Post)(nil)).Elem()},
}

// User is xorm struct
type User struct {
   Id   int64
   Name string
}

// Post is xorm struct
type Post struct {
   Post_id int64
   Name    string
   Other   string
}
```

Note you must use exported fields!

And then handling the tables:

```
for _, rec := range ListOfTables {
    entries := reflect.New(reflect.SliceOf(t.XormStruct)).Interface()
    err := xorm.Find(entries)
    // Handle error

    err := xml.Marshal(entries)
    // Handle error
}
```

You can see a working example (proof of concept) of this (without `xorm` as that is not available on the Go Playground) using JSON: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/N92gZgxxJWG).

If you were to store `reflect.Type` values of slices in the first place:

```
var ListOfTables [...]Record {
   {"User", "id", reflect.TypeOf([]User{})},
   {"Post", "post_id", reflect.TypeOf([]Post{})},
}
```

And using it is also simpler:

```
for _, rec := range ListOfTables {
    entries := reflect.New(t.XormStruct).Interface()
    err := xorm.Find(entries)
    // Handle error

    err := xml.Marshal(entries)
    // Handle error
}
```

See proof of concept of this: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/X9odLMedemE).

Note that if `Record` holds slice types (in the field `XormStruct`), should you ever need to access the type of the struct (the element type of the struct), you may use `Type.Elem()` for that.

Comment: Either of these approaches does not produce any errors, however result it is the same as my attempt to store `XormStruct interface{}`.

`xorm.Find(&entries)` return an empty `&[]` Maybe the problem lies with xorm itself?

Comment: @liepumartins Make sure your mapping is correct. For example as I noted in the answer, you cannot use unexported fields (you must start field names with uppercase letters).

Comment: I do have exported fields, sorry example was incorrect on that part. I updated question to illustrate what I mean with my previous comment.

Comment: Please post the exact code that uses my solution and does not work for you. The code you included in the question is a "hybrid" of my and your solution, and wouldn't even compile. Also show if and how you handle errors.

Comment: Problem was `xorm.Find(&entries)` should be `xorm.Find(entries)` if your solution is used, thanks!

Comment: @liepumartins Yup, sorry about that. My working playground links used `entries`, but left the `&` sign in them when merged my playground solution with yours. Yes, it must be simply `entries` as that is already a pointer.