# Is it possible to dynamically set the output of json.Unmarshal?

Tags: json, go, reflection

I have the following Go code:

```
var typeRegistry = make(map[string]reflect.Type)

func init() {
    typeRegistry["User"] = reflect.TypeOf(User{})
}

func makeInstance(name string) interface{} {
    v := reflect.New(typeRegistry[name]).Elem()
    return v.Interface()
}

func Invoke(any interface{}, name string, body []byte, signature Signature) {
    args := signature.Args
    data := makeInstance(signature.Args[0])
    json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
    inputs := make([]reflect.Value, len(args))
    for i, _ := range signature.Args {
        log.Println(reflect.TypeOf(data))
        log.Println(reflect.ValueOf(data))
        inputs[i] = reflect.ValueOf(data)
    }
    reflect.ValueOf(any).MethodByName(name).Call(inputs)
}
```

I'm attempting to pass in some JSON, and a string denoting what type the JSON should be mapped to. I'm attempting to use reflection to mush the two together again and pass it into a method by the methods name.

I kind of got it working, however, when I use a pointer un `json.Unmarshal` it seems to lose the reference to its assigned type again, and defaults back to `map[string]interface{}` which is a mis-match for the method I'm calling. In this case it's expecting type `main.User`. If I remove the pointer from `json.Unmarshal(body, data)` the types match correctly, but obviously the data is no longer being set for `data`.

I'm aware I'm bastardising Go's type-system, and probably using the language in ways that isn't suggested, but I'm trying to do something more academic than useful, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a pointer to `json.Unmarshal()`, else it can't change the (pointed) data, only a copy of it. This is what happens when you pass `data`: since it can't change the value (non-pointer value of type `User` wrapped in `interface{}`), therefore it creates a new value it can unmarshal into. And it will choose whatever it sees fit bests (but it won't be `User` but rather `map[string]interface{}` as you experienced).

So yes, you have to pass a pointer to it, but `&data` will not be what you want. `&data` will be a pointer to interface, of type `*interface{}` because `makeInstance()` returns a value of `interface{}` type, so `data` will have that inferred type.

The solution is to change `makeInstance()` to return a pointer which may be wrapped in an `interface{}` value, that's ok. And then you may simply pass `data` to `json.Unmarshal()`, because the `data` interface value will hold a value of type `*User`.

So do:

```
func makeInstance(name string) interface{} {
    v := reflect.New(typeRegistry[name]) // Don't call Elem() here
    return v.Interface()
}
```

And in `Invoke()`:

```
data := makeInstance(signature.Args[0])
json.Unmarshal(body, data)
```

See related question that was posted just a few hours ago:

[Store information/reference about structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963237/store-information-reference-about-structure/52965065#52965065)

You can see a working demo here: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/N92gZgxxJWG).