# How to declare the Type of a variable dynamically in GO, using if-else-like conditions?

Tags: json, go, if-statement, unmarshalling, type-definition

Given two types

```
type A struct {
    ID         string
    Content    []int
}
```

and

```
type B struct {
    ID         string
    Content    map[string][]int
}
```

and I need a function to tell me which type to use hereafter according to conditions (the purpose is to unmarshal a json string properly). I want a function like

```
func assign_typed_data(header string) interface{} {
    switch header {
    case "A" :
         d := new(A)
         fmt.Printf('inner type is %T \n', *d)      // inner type is A
         return *d
    case "B" :
         d := new(B)
         fmt.Printf('inner type is %T \n', *d)      // inner type is B
         return *d
    default:
    }
}
```

and in the outer code I can call it and unmarshal the json like follows, but the returned value turns to "map[string]interface{}".

```
header := "A"
data := assign_typed_data(header)
fmt.Printf('outter type is %T \n', data)      // outter type is map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal(json_data, &data)
```

I also tried simple if-else statements in the outter code directly without calling a function, like follows, but failed as well because of defined scope is local.

```
if header == "A" {
    data := *new(A)
}else if header == "B" {
    data := *new(B)
}
json.Unmarshal(json_data, &data)
```

Is there a possible way to achieve this goal in GO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a pointer to the expected data type to [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal). That is, `*A` or `*B`.

Yet, `assign_typed_data()` returns `interface{}` and you take its address, so you'll be passing `*interface{}`.

Change `assign_typed_data()` to return the pointer value `*A` or `*B`, and pass `data` as-is to `json.Unmarshal()` as it will already hold a pointer value:

```
func createValue(header string) interface{} {
    switch header {
    case "A":
        d := new(A)
        fmt.Printf("inner type is %T \n", d) // inner type is *A
        return d
    case "B":
        d := new(B)
        fmt.Printf("inner type is %T \n", d) // inner type is *B
        return d
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
s := `{"ID":"abc","Content":[1,2,3]}`
data := createValue("A")
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), data); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("outer type is %T \n", data)
fmt.Printf("outer value is %+v \n", data)

s = `{"ID":"abc","Content":{"one":[1,2], "two":[3,4]}}`
data = createValue("B")
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), data); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("outer type is %T \n", data)
fmt.Printf("outer value is %+v \n", data)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fYCVGgkVZ7D)):

```
inner type is *main.A 
outer type is *main.A 
outer value is &{ID:abc Content:[1 2 3]} 
inner type is *main.B 
outer type is *main.B 
outer value is &{ID:abc Content:map[one:[1 2] two:[3 4]]}
```

Please check related / possible duplicates which detail the issue further:

[Golang interface{} type misunderstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829941/golang-interface-type-misunderstanding/38830638#38830638)

[Is it possible to dynamically set the output of json.Unmarshal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52970019/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-set-the-output-of-json-unmarshal/52970254#52970254)

[How to tell json.Unmarshal to use struct instead of interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779319/how-to-tell-json-unmarshal-to-use-struct-instead-of-interface/44779409#44779409)

Comment: in your code, `data` seems to be `*main.A` type, valued by `&{ID:abc Content:[1 2 3]}`, but when accessing its pointing value using `temp := *data`, compiler reports error `invalid operation: cannot indirect data (variable of type interface{})`. Would you please explain on it and give a method of accessing "*data"? Thank you.

Comment: @xcwang `data` has static type `interface{}` but dynamic type `*main.A`. To access the value stored in the interface value, use type assertion, e.g. `data.(*A).ID`.